# Rectangle node with given coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I make a tikz rectangle node with given lower-left and upper-right corners, having a given border color and fill color?  I know it seems like a basic question, but I cannot find an example in the manual!  I tried this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [shape=rectangle, thin, color=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.4, minimum width=0.5599999999999998, minimum height=3.3999999999999995, above right] (A) at (1.4000000000000001, -3.0999999999999996) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a node? If not you can do something like `\filldraw [draw=blue,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That's fine, but then how do I place another node using the anchor "above" or "below"?

Comment: Well, that would be a reason for having it as a `node` I guess. You would have to use explicit coordinates (or a coordinate calculated from the corners) instead of referring to the node name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `fit` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
myrect/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw,
  inner sep=0pt,
  fit=#1}
]
\coordinate (A) at (2,3);
\coordinate (B) at (-3,4);
\coordinate (C) at (0,2);
\coordinate (D) at (-5,6);
\coordinate (E) at (5,-2);
\node[myrect={(A) (B)}] {}; 
\node[myrect={(C) (D)},draw=cyan,rounded corners] {}; 
\node[myrect={(A) (E)},draw=cyan,fill=orange,line width=2pt] {}; 
\foreach \Coord in {A,B,C,D,E}
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=\Coord] at (\Coord) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should note that the `fit` node will add a (potentially invisible) border, in addition to any `inner sep`. To use the node's anchors later on, instead of `draw`ing it, one should use `inner sep=0pt,line width=0pt`.